# Suggest a suitable algorithm for merging two arrays containing class objects (without duplication)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have an array where each position contains a class object with three int values (x,y,z). now from an  different array all the elements have to be copied into source array. For each array element we need to check for x,y,z values in order to avoid duplication. Is it possible to do more efficiently than o(n^2) ?

Comment: I guess these arrays are not sorted, right?

Comment: Only if you are prepared to sort your arrays.

Comment: you can use a hash table of the string representation for the 3 int values. and i'm guessing (1,2,3) differ from (2,1,3). right...?

Comment: @KirilKirov: You make O(n²) sound as if its a good idea :)

Answer (score 6):

Provided that you don't mind losing the original order of the two arrays:

```
std::sort(first_array, first_array + N);
std::sort(second_array, second_array + M);
std::set_union(
    first_array, first_array+N, 
    second_array, second_array+M, 
    target_array
);
```

`N` and `M` are the numbers of elements in the arrays. You need to either define `operator<` or specialize `std::less` for your class: alternatively write a comparator function and supply it to `sort` and `set_union`.

Time complexity is `O(N log N + M log M)` -- the `sort` is the slower part and then `set_union` is linear.

If `first_array` or `second_array` might already contain dupes within themselves (not just between them), then you need an extra step to remove them, which loses not just the order but also the dupes in the source arrays:

```
std::sort(first_array, first_array + N);
MyClass *first_end = std::unique(first_array, first_array + N);
std::sort(second_array, second_array + M);
MyClass *second_end = std::unique(second_array, second_array + M);
std::set_union(
    first_array, first_end, 
    second_array, second_end, 
    target_array
);
```

Alternatively you could write a modified version of `set_union` that merges and dedupes in a single pass.

[Edit: sorry, in writing this I missed that the result is eventually going back into `first_array`, not into a separate `target_array`. `set_union` doesn't work with the output as one of the inputs, so this also requires extra memory for the target array, which can then be copied back to the source array assuming of course that the source is big enough.]

If you do want to preserve the order of the original arrays, then you can create a container and check as you go:

```
container<MyClass> items(first_array, first_array + N);
MyClass *dst = first_array + N;
for (MyClass *it = second_array; it != second_array + M; ++it) {
    if (items.count(*it) == 0) {
        items.insert(*it);
        *dst++ = *it;
    }
}
```

If the arrays can contain dupes within themselves then start with `items` empty and `dst = first_array`, then loop over both input arrays.

`container` could be `std::set` (in which case time is `O(N log N + M log(N + M))`, which in fact is `O(N log N + M log M)` again, and you still need an order comparator), or else `std::unordered_set` in C++11 (in which case expected time is `O(N + M)` with pathological worst-cases, and you need to specialize `std::hash` or otherwise write a hash function and also provide an equals function, instead of an order comparator). Prior to C++11, other hash containers are available just not in the standard.

If you don't mind the extra memory *and* don't mind losing the original order:

```
container<MyClass> items(first_array, first_array + N);
items.insert(second_array, second_array + M);
std::copy(items.begin(), items.end(), first_array);
```

If you don't want to use (much) extra memory and have space in the source array for M additional elements, as opposed to merely having space for the result:

```
std::copy(second_array, second_array + M, first_array + N);
std::sort(first_array, first_array + N + M);
MyClass *dst = std::unique(first_array, first_array + N + M);
// result now has (dst - first_array) elements
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a comparison on your objects using x,y,z, sort both arrays (or copies, if necessary), then create a secondary destination list into which you copy all elements from the first, and only nonmatching elements from the second. If necessary, copy back into the first array.

Complexity: max(O(n log n),O(m log m)), since the sorting dominates, and filling the destination list is on O(max(n,m)).

That isn't to say the algorithm is necessarily efficient: for smaller arrays, the copying and sorting will dominate.